# which android toolkit functions/classes would I need to use to implement a slingshot mechanism in an android game?

Tags: android, algorithm, game-physics, toolkit

which android toolkit functions/classes would I need to use to implement a slingshot like character control mechanism? (for android game) I want a character that can fly around by repeatedly being slingshotted like on angry birds (only repeatedly). Any help is greatly appreciated.

also, I would like to implement it into the framework presented in [here](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-7-creating-an-android-game-from-start-to-finish.html) if possible, since i followed the tutorial succesfully and completed it.

can someone at least point me in the right direction for what to research?

alright everyone I'm sorry I asked this question, I did more research and am now watching some AndEngine tutorials so I can try to figure out how to make a slingshot mechanism myself using that framework. Would anyone mind canceling the minus' so I can post correct specific questions again?

Comment: why was I minus'd? I tried researching the topic but couldn't find any help on it...

Comment: 'Which functions/classes' and 'what to research' questions are not really appropriate for [so]. Your problem description is not very clear. The question doesn't show any attempt at solving the problem yourself (it's possibly understandable **why** the question doesn't show this, but maybe the down-voters didn't agree).

Comment: I want to give you a minus for you offensive profile picture :|

Comment: oh come on its not that bad

Comment: @JL It's mildly offensive. Remember that [so] consists of members of all ages from many different countries with vastly different cultures that may not be nearly on the same page as you as to what's appropriate / offensive.

Comment: Ok I changed the picture, I'm sorry I was being offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would require a lot of mathematics.  Also, a lot of drawing.

For the Android part, you can start with a `View` and implement the `onTouchEvent`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

Although, I am sure there is a more effective way of creating a game for Android.
Possibly using some type of rapid development kit to reduce the amount of background code you'd have to write.
For example, write your application in Flash or AdobeAir and deploy it that way.

I think you were down voted because a lot of your questioning can be answered by doing your own research.  There is no error here, you are basically asking for code.

Here some stuff you can search for:

- Slingshot physics
- Collision detection
- Android View drawing
- Android OpenGL ES

Comment: if i use such a rapid development kit though will I be able to use things like the android game center equivalent? and is there a good rapid development kit thats permanently free?

Comment: READ the information on this page: http://gaming.adobe.com/

Comment: I did...... its not free... a rep even said so..